¿Cómo pasar un array de PHP a Javascript? (Error)
Estoy trayendo un array de PHP y necesito manipularlo con Javascript. Lo que me parece extraño es que en el servidor no me arroja ningún error pero cuando lo pruebo en localhost me sale el siguiente error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'

Esto es lo que me muestra en la consola de comandos:
let array_clientes = ;

En otras palabras no me está imprimiendo el array que traigo de PHP y no se le está asignando ningún valor al array_clientes de JS.
Este es el código en Javascript que aplico:
let array_clientes = <?php echo json_encode($clientes) ?>;

No entiendo por qué no me imprime el array con la función json_encode de PHP, por eso es que no se le está asignando ningún valor a la variable array_clientes de JS .
Repito, este problema sólo lo tengo en el localhost pero en el servidor sí me funciona sin problema alguno.
Hice var_dump($clientes) y esto me arrojó:
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(28) {
    ["Id"]=>
    int(3)
    [0]=>
    int(3)
    ["Nombre"]=>
    string(17) "Jesús Neyra"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "Jesús Neyra"
    ["Portada"]=>
    string(5) "foto"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "foto"
    ["Sexo"]=>
    string(6) "hombre"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "hombre"
    ["Descripcion"]=>
    string(196) "Cliente premium renovable cada año"
    [4]=>
    string(196) "Cliente premium renovable cada año"
    ["Servicios"]=>
    string(91) "telefonía fija y cable"
    [5]=>
    string(91) "telefonía fija y cable"
    ["Publico"]=>
    string(7) "local"
    [6]=>
    string(7) "local"
    ["Lugar_atencion"]=>
    string(27) "domicilio centro comercial"
    [7]=>
    string(27) "domicilio centro comercial"
    ["Lugar_publicacion"]=>
    string(4) "Lima"
    [8]=>
    string(4) "Lima"
    ["Pais_publicacion"]=>
    string(4) "Peru"
    [9]=>
    string(4) "Peru"
    ["Fecha_inicio"]=>
    string(10) "2023-10-11"
    [10]=>
    string(10) "2023-10-11"
    ["Fecha_fin"]=>
    string(10) "2024-10-11"
    [11]=>
    string(10) "2024-10-11"
    ["Telefono"]=>
    string(11) "519457603"
    [12]=>
    string(11) "519457603"
    ["Correo"]=>
    string(21) "jesus_neyra@gmail.com"
    [13]=>
    string(21) "jesus_neyra@gmail.com"
  }
}

No entiendo por qué me recoge datos duplicados por cada campo de la tabla

var_dump a $clientes y lo agregas la pregunta

¿Por casualidad la variable $clientes está indefinida cuando ejecutas en local?

@Yussef Hola, acabo de hacer el var_dump que me recomendaste y lo edité en la pregunta. Lo que no entiendo es por qué me está recogiendo catos duplicados por cada campo de la consulta a la base de datos.

@jachguate Hola, sí, la variable $clientes ya está previamente definida cuando realizo la consulta a la base de datos vía PHP. Hice var_dump y me botó un array con datos duplicados por cada campo de la tabla. Lo acabo de editar en la pregunta si puedes revisar.

Creo que es momento de echarle un ojo a los datos que están en la DB y al código donde se inicializa esa variable $clientes.
